# Can we call 2 actions in one button click? [palantir]

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I am trying to do 2 actions at a time:

1. Calculate a scenario in one submit action. (calling a function)
2. Save some KPIs after that. (modify object)

How can I do this in one click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way to do this is to author a function that does both. The resulting function to do the calculations needed and save the results in memory. Then by calling [ontology-edits api](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/api-ontology-edits/), you can choose to propagate those results and be saved to whatever object is within context.